# Add Email Notification for Newsfeed

Tags: sharepoint-online, newsfeed, notifications

We have a departmental newsfeed that I would like to have email notifications for. I was told that this is possible and I referenced this article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-newsfeed-settings-dbb4db06-37c2-4e75-bc08-1ecf144fbd8d

However, when I click on my profile name, I do not have an "About Me" page setting to go into to change Newsfeed Settings.
How can I enable this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type the edit profile address in the address bar as below:

https://domain -my.sharepoint.com/personal/username_domain_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/**editprofile.aspx**